# Contar número de elementos repetidos en un array y cuántas veces se repiten

Tags: javascript, array, angularjs, bucle-for

Me pierdo un poco con las estructuras de objetos, dentro arrays, dentro objetos...etc. Al hacer `onchange` en un select de opciones, quiero que compruebe cuántas veces se repite un elemento, en **caso de que se repita más de 2 veces (una la que está añadida en el array y otra la que elijo en el select)**, desactivará el botón "Añadir" y mandará mensaje al usuario por ejemplo.

El problema es que no consigo contar el número de veces que se repite al ser una estructura más "complicada" de lo normal.

Aquí está un ejemplo del objeto:

```
var obj = {
    "id" : "5d00f4fb87502b3a9b751152",
    "name" : "ExampleName1",
    "products" : [ 
        {
            "brands" : [ 
                {
                    "user" : "CLIENT",
                    "typeProd" : ["TIPO1", "TIPO3"],
                    "id" : "5d5f963b205d534adc78242f",
                    "template" : {
                        id: "5d4s7204b1d3ess8ba0e41ce"
                        category: "GENERAL",
                        code: "CODE1"
                    }
                }, 
                {
                    "user" : "ADMIN",
                    "typeProd" : ["TIPO1", "TIPO2"],
                    "id" : "5d5f963b205d534adc78242e",
                    "template" : {
                        id: "5d4s7204b1d3ahs77shhssb"
                        category: "GENERAL",
                        code: "CODE2"
                    }
                }, 
                {
                    "user" : null,
                    "typeProd" : [],
                    "id" : "5d5f963b205d534adc78242d"
                }, 
                {
                    "user" : "CLIENT",
                    "typeProd" : ["TIPO1", "TIPO3"],
                    "id" : "5d5f963b205d534adc78242c",
                    "template" : {
                        id: "5d4s7204b1d3ess8ba0e41ce"
                        category: "GENERAL",
                        code: "CODE1"
                    }
                }
            ]
        }
    ]
}
```

Necesitaré que cuente cuántas veces se repite `obj.products.brands.template`, ¿cúantas `template` hay repetidas por cada `code`. En el caso del ejemplo, se repitén la 1 y 4.

Lo que tengo hasta el momento:

```
for (var i = 0; i < $scope.obj.products[productIndex].brands.length; i++) {

  console.log('Template '+ i);
  console.log($scope.obj.products[productIndex].brands[i]);

  var obje =  $scope.obj.products[productIndex].brands[i].template;
  var templates =  $scope.obj.products[productIndex].brands[i].template;
  var templateCode = $scope.obj.products[productIndex].brands[i].template.code;


  if (Object.entries(obje).length === 0 && obje.constructor === Object) {
    console.log('Object '+ i + ' is empty');
  }

  //Comprobar si template está repetido más de 2 veces con el mismo code

}
```

*** He editado la pregunta, me gustaría que se buscase por pares `id` y `typeProd` (mismo array de valores) o bien por pares `code` y `typeProd`.

Comment: El ejemplo no deja claro todos los escenarios: ¿Cuándo se considera un elemento repetido? ¿Quieres comparar el campo template.id, o la pareja (template.id, template.code)? ¿Qué tipo de respuesta esperas de la función que busque los repetidos?

Comment: template.id y template.code serán una pareja que se repita siempre, me da igual por cuál de los dos comparar o los dos a la vez. Un elemento repetido será aquel que tenga mismo id y code. Gracias por tu ayuda y siento si la explicación no es demasiado buena, se me hace difícil reflejar el funcionamiento

Answer (score 4):

Esto Filtra todos brands que tengan el mismo id y el mismo id de template.

```
var repeats = $scope.obj.products[productIndex].brands.filter((brand) =>  {
  if(brand.id && brand.template) {
    if(brand.template.id){
      return brand.id == brand.template.id;
    }
  }
});
var numberRepeats = repeats.length;
```

Y esto que creo que es lo que de verdad buscas, cuenta cada brand y mira cuantes veces su template id es repetido sin ser el mismo:

```
var brands = $scope.obj.products[productIndex].brands;

brands.forEach((brand) => {
  if(brand.template){
    var repeat = brands.filter((_brand) => {
       if(_brand.id && _brand.template)
        if(brand.template.id) {
          return brand.template.id == _brand.template.id 
                && brand.id != _brand.id;
        }
       return false;
    });
    console.log("El brand "+ brand.id + " con template.id:" + brand.template.id + " se repite " + repeat.length + " veces");
  }
});
```

Te lo edito, pero deberias mirar como funcionan las funciones:

- Map
- ForEach
- Filter
- includes

```js
var brands = [
    {
        "user": "CLIENT",
        "typeProd": ["TIPO1", "TIPO3"],
        "id": "5d5f963b205d534adc78242f",
        "template": {
            id: "5d4s7204b1d3ess8ba0e41ce",
            category: "GENERAL",
            code: "CODE1"
        }
    },
    {
        "user": "ADMIN",
        "typeProd": ["TIPO1", "TIPO2"],
        "id": "5d5f963b205d534adc78242e",
        "template": {
            id: "5d4s7204b1d3ahs77shhssb",
            category: "GENERAL",
            code: "CODE2"
        }
    },
    {
        "user": null,
        "typeProd": [],
        "id": "5d5f963b205d534adc78242d"
    },
    {
        "user": "CLIENT",
        "typeProd": ["TIPO1", "TIPO3"],
        "id": "5d5f963b205d534adc78242c",
        "template": {
            id: "5d4s7204b1d3ess8ba0e41ce",
            category: "GENERAL",
            code: "CODE1"
        }
    }
];

var compareArray = (arr1, arr2) => {
    var result = true;
    if (arr1.length != arr2.length) {
        return false;
    }
    arr1.forEach((i) => {
        result = result && arr2.includes(i);
    })
    return result;
}

brands.forEach((brand) => {
    if (brand.template && brand.typeProd) {
        var repeat = brands.filter((_brand) => {
            if (_brand.id && _brand.template && _brand.typeProd)
                if (brand.template.id) {
                    return (
                            brand.template.id == _brand.template.id
                            ||  // Usa && Si quieres que tenga el id y el mismo typeProd
                            compareArray(_brand.typeProd, brand.typeProd)
                        )
                        && brand.id != _brand.id;
                }
            return false;
        });
        console.log("El brand " + brand.id + " con template.id:" + brand.template.id + " se repite " + repeat.length + " veces");
    }
});
```

Comment: Funciona perfecto!! Lo acabo de testear y mil gracias! Pondré tu pregunta como correcta, pero podrías ayudarme en una última cosa? he editado el enunciado. Me gustaría que buscase repetidos que tengan mismo id y también typeProduct (es un array con strings)